# Modern css/jquery bubble animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

Basically I received help to alter a codepen and was happy with the end result, but then when i tried to implement it on a html web page, it doesn't render properly and i'm not sure where it goes wrong, here is the link to the code pen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hsepG

and here is my attempted implementation:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<title>test</title>
<style>
@mixin animate($animation, $duration, $repeat, $easing) {
-webkit-animation: $animation $duration $repeat $easing;
   -moz-animation: $animation $duration $repeat $easing;
    -ms-animation: $animation $duration $repeat $easing;
        animation: $animation $duration $repeat $easing;
}

@mixin keyframes($name) {
@-webkit-keyframes #{$name} {
    @content; 
}
@-moz-keyframes #{$name} {
    @content;
}
@-ms-keyframes #{$name} {
    @content;
}
@keyframes #{$name} {
    @content;
} 
}

html,
body {
height: 100%;
}

body {
background: #09f;

@include background-image(linear-gradient(left, #09f, #45d1ff));
}

.bubble-toggle {
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
right: 10px;
padding: 10px;
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 13px;
color: #333;

&:hover {
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
}
}

.bubbles {
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.bubble-container {  
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;

@include animate(bubblerise, 4s, infinite, ease-in);
@include opacity(0);
}

.bubble {  
width: 6px;
height: 6px;
margin: 0 auto;
border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.25);

@include border-radius(10px);
@include animate(bubblewobble, 0.4s, infinite, linear);
}

@include keyframes(bubblerise) {
0% {    
    bottom: 0;

@include opacity(0);
}
5% {    
    bottom: 0;

@include opacity(1);
}
99% {
    @include opacity(1);
}
100% {    
    bottom: 100%;

@include opacity(0);
}
}

@include keyframes(bubblewobble) {
0% {
    margin-left: 0;
}
50% {
    margin-left: 2px;
}
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="bubbles"></div>
<a class="bubble-toggle" href="#">Bubbles Off</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
var $bubbles = $('.bubbles');

function bubbles() {

// Settings
var min_bubble_count = 20, // Minimum number of bubbles
  max_bubble_count = 40, // Maximum number of bubbles
  min_bubble_size = 3, // Smallest possible bubble diameter (px)
  max_bubble_size = 8; // Largest possible bubble diameter (px)

// Calculate a random number of bubbles based on our min/max
var bubbleCount = min_bubble_count + Math.floor(Math.random() * (max_bubble_count + 1));

// Create the bubbles
for (var i = 0; i < bubbleCount; i++) {
$bubbles.append('<div class="bubble-container"><div class="bubble"></div></div>');
}

// Now randomise the various bubble elements
$bubbles.find('.bubble-container').each(function(){

// Randomise the bubble positions (0 - 100%)
var pos_rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);

// Randomise their size
var size_rand = min_bubble_size + Math.floor(Math.random() * (max_bubble_size + 1));

// Randomise the time they start rising (0-15s)
var delay_rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16);

// Randomise their speed (3-8s)
var speed_rand = 0.5 + Math.random() * 2;

// Cache the this selector
var $this = $(this);

// Apply the new styles
$this.css({
  'left' : pos_rand + '%',

  '-webkit-animation-duration' : speed_rand + 's',
  '-moz-animation-duration' : speed_rand + 's',
  '-ms-animation-duration' : speed_rand + 's',
  'animation-duration' : speed_rand + 's',

  '-webkit-animation-delay' : delay_rand + 's',
  '-moz-animation-delay' : delay_rand + 's',
  '-ms-animation-delay' : delay_rand + 's',
  'animation-delay' : delay_rand + 's'
});

$this.children('.bubble').css({
  'width' : size_rand + 'px',
  'height' : size_rand + 'px'
});

});
}

// In case users value their laptop battery life
// Allow them to turn the bubbles off
$('.bubble-toggle').click(function(){
if($bubbles.is(':empty')) {
bubbles();
$bubbles.show();
$(this).text('Bubbles Off');
} else {
$bubbles.fadeOut(function(){
  $(this).empty();
});
$(this).text('Bubbles On');
}

return false;
});

bubbles();

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Should my Css be in a separate style sheet?

thanks

Comment: Wrap your jquery code in a $( document ).ready() function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your codepen is using SCSS, not straight CSS.  See http://sass-lang.com.

So, to use it on your own web page, you'll need to compile the SCSS, or copy the compiled CSS from the code pen.  To get the compiled CSS from the codepen click on `(SCSS)`.

[image]